# How to protect a virtual directory with a password in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, clickonce, passwords

I've placed a ClickOnce deployment inside of a virtual directory on a server running IIS7.

I would like to be able to password protect the directory so I can test the application out on the WAN but I can't seem to find out how to set a password for the directory containing the ClickOnce app.

Any help would be very much appriciated.

Comment: Please move this to Serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of authentication do you want to use?  A simple thing to do is enable Windows authentication on the directory, then add allow/deny authorization rules.  This can all be done through the IIS management console.  Windows authentication may not be installed, so you may need to install it as a feature.

Comment: I'm open to anything that works - we're not going to be deploying this, we're just looking to do some informal testing.  I don't think I saw windows authentication as an option..

The options I have are:
Anonymous
ASP .NET impersonation
Forms Authentication

Comment: Is this Windows Server 2008 or Vista?  If it's 2k8, you can add Windows authentication through the Add Features area of the management console.  If it's Vista, you'll have to do it through the control panel's "Turn Windows features on or off" interface.

Comment: Thanks, it's Server 2008.  I just added windows authentication - followed these directions :

http://weblogs.asp.net/zroiy/archive/2008/08/17/missing-windows-authentication-provider-for-iis-7-on-windows-server-2008.aspx

But no new authentication methods were added to the listing.  I'm restarting to see if they show up after the reboot.

Comment: That did it... I selected Windows authentication after the reboot and used a local user account.  Perfect.